# iOS UILocalNotification not updating app icon

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icons, uilocalnotification

first of all, I'm really thankful for all your help.

I need just one more little help.

I finished my app, and I used UILocalNotifications to fire some reminders. The app icon is always with a "1" saying there is 1 new notification on the app but it is like that for ever, even if there is no notification. How can I fix this?

Other detail, when the user slides the app icon when iPhone fires the notification (outside the app when the iPhone is locked or when the app is in the background), I would like the app to load in the main view. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the badge number inside you application delegate code, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveLocalNotification: as appropriate. i.e.

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

I don't understand your second question.
If you want to change the view it displays depending upon how its launched then you can do so, once again this would be in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or didReceiveLocalNotification.

Comment: The second question is: How do I force system to go to main view when local notification is received?

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification: is called, switch to the view controller or view that displays your main view when that happens.